# In symfony 1.4, is there a way to override or extend parts of a generated schema.yml?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

We are using symfony 1.4 with doctrine.  Because of the nature of our development, the three of us working on this project need to regenerate our schema, model, forms and filters every morning.

I want to keep a table set as "versionable" in the schema.  If I re-generate the schema with `php symfony doctrine:build-schema`, the resulting file does not have the `actAs:` in it anymore, and I need to copy and paste before re-generating my model, forms and filters.

Is there a way to extend the `schema.yml` so that we can avoid copying and pasting a snippet of code every morning to keep that configuration constant?  If so, how far do I need to go in the extending file?  For example, can I include only the `actAs:` for that individual table, or do I need to define the table in its entirety?

Comment: Why are you creating your schema.yml from you database when you could do the other way round?

Comment: The quick answer is that this isn't the way we want to do it.  We're each working on independent local copies of a main database, and we don't want to modify that main database until after our local development and testing of a module is completed, but we do want to be able to update our local database with committed changes.  Up until now, importing modified/added tables has worked fine.  Versionable is the only hiccup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you regenerate your model, you only regenerate the base* files. Extending the setup() method contained in the Base* classes in the * classes (you can find them one directory up) might be a solution to add you versionnable behavior permanently. But I think the most handy would be to import modified schema.yml instead of modified tables, unless you don't want to loose your data. Can't you apply a version of your schema.yml only to development machines by using a branch?

Comment: Extending the SetUp() method worked exactly as I needed it to.  Thanks for your help!